# Executar aplicação através de serviço delphi com direitos de administrador

Tags: delphi

Necessito executar uma aplicação através de serviço em `delphi` com direitos elevados de administrador.

Já tentei várias soluções encontradas aqui, tais como

```
RunAsAdminAndWaitForCompletion(filename,
  Parameters: string; wait: boolean): Boolean;
```

Contudo a aplicação quando é executada pelo serviço, fica sem direitos de administrador.

Uma simples impressão pela aplicação que foi chamada não é executada, porque a aplicação chamada fica sem acesso aos periféricos. Como é que posso fazer para que a aplicação que for executada através do serviço, seja executada com privilégios de administrador sobre a máquina.

O usuário que encontra-se logado na máquina já é administrador.

Answer (score 0):

Cara, eu tava dando uma pesquisada rápida e encontrei isso aqui:

```
uses ShellApi;

ShellExecute(Handle, 'runas', 'regedit', nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Eu testei aqui no Delphi XE5 com um aplicação comum e funcionou certinho (coloquei um botão no form e no *click* dele eu coloquei esse comando), você pode ver que o comando que eu estou chamando é o *Regedit* e esse carinha só é aberto com permissão de admin.

Da um testada aí no seu caso pra ver se resolve seu problema, qualquer coisa comenta aí que a gente vai se falando.

Abraço.

Comment: Eu usei o Delphi XE5 em um projeto VCL - Forms Application, não sei qual é a versão do Delphi que você está usando aí.